# Error 97 when calling socket() on Debian inside VirtualBox

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am working on creating a simple server in C. Right now I'm having trouble creating the socket to listen for incoming connections.
I am on an x86 **Debian** distro running inside **VirtualBox**.
My code is as follows:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>    /* threads, yo */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>     /* memset */

#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* helpers like inet_ntop */ 
#include <netinet/in.h>

void listenInput();

void* handleConn(void* args) {
    printf("Handling connection!\n");
    listenInput();
    return NULL;
}

void acceptData(int socket) {


}

void listenInput() {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *sockadr;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int status;
    struct addrinfo *p = sockadr;
    int s;
    int yes = 1;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    printf("Getting addr info. Preparing to listen on port 8080\n");
    if((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8080", &hints, &sockadr)) != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return;
    }

    printf("Woo, got addr info!\n");
    printf("Calling socket(...)\n");
    if( -1 == (s = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol))) {
        printf("Error creating socket (%d): %s\n", errno, gai_strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

        printf("Calling bind\n");
        bind(s, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);

        printf("Calling listen...\n");
        listen(s, 5);
        {
            struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
            socklen_t addr_size = sizeof their_addr;

            printf("accept()...\n");
            int newsocket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);

            printf("Got a connection! New socket: %d\n", newsocket);
        }

        close(s);


    freeaddrinfo(sockadr);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t   thread;
    void*       status;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handleConn, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, &status);
    printf("Joined thread!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When running this, `socket()` fails with an error code 97 - Address family not supported.
I have failed to find any relevant information about this issue so far.

Here is the output of `ifconfig` inside my virtual machine:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:11:84:ee  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe11:84ee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17778 (17.3 KiB)  TX bytes:14571 (14.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4652 (4.5 KiB)  TX bytes:4652 (4.5 KiB)
```

Moreover, `netstat --tcp` shows other stream sockets listening, so other apps seem to succeed creating them.

Comment: you're initializing hints correctly, but i can't see, where you're initializing sockaddr. yet you're making an alias of it (p) and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your actions with getaddrinfo() call slightly incorrect.

1. You set pointer *p:

   ```
   p = sockadr;
   ```
2. You pass *&sockadr* as last argument to getaddrinfo():

   ```
   status = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8080", &hints, &sockadr)
   ```
3. You use **old** value of *sockadr* (through *p*) in calls to *socket()* and *bind()*

Please note: *&sockadr* is pointer to pointer, so it can **change** address *sockadr* points to. And this is what exactly happens. If you print *sockadr* as pointer before and after *getaddrinfo()* you see it:

> sockadr before getaddrinfo(): 0x7fef07d8fee2
>
> Getting addr info. Preparing to listen on port 8080
>
> sockadr after getaddrinfo(): 0x7fef000008c0

So, possible solution is to add this line after *getaddrinfo()* call:

```
p = sockadr;
```

See `man 3 getaddrinfo` for usage example.

PS. I like your code though. It is clean and almost right.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. So, in conclusion, it is because of a mangled pointer that that error was being thrown at me. This threw me off, but now I understand.